# Mod rewrite for multiple sub folders giving problems htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Having an issue with my mod rewrite for htaccess.
I have got this to work so far but now i am facing an issue with getting the pages to pick up correctly i take it my issues is with RewriteBase /

The errors i am getting are:

Not Found

The requested URL /systemfiles/cms-widgets-update-3column-image.php was not found on this server.

and

Not Found

The requested URL /templates/index.php was not found on this server.

here is my code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !(.*)/systemfiles
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ systemfiles/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URL} !(.*)/templates
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ templates/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Your first 2 rewriteconds look out of place. They will only work for the first rewriterule. Also your rewriterules are essentially the same. How will the server know which one to send to? It's going to go to the first rule. Also it's `%{REQUEST_URI}` not URL, so those conditions aren't helping you.

Comment: May you please assist me on the correct track please

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to accomplish. Can you give more exmples and example urls. Also note if they are real files or not. Edit your question with this info.

Comment: So i have 2 folders in my project, 1. system files and 2. templates. when i type in signin.php which is in my system file it should know that it is in my system folder or if i go to the websites index.php file it should know its in my templates folder... i would like not like to display the folder names in the URL. etc www.mywebsite.com/systemfiles/signin.php should just be www.mywebsite.com/signin.php and www.mywebsite.com/templates/index.php should be www.mywebsite.com/index.php

Comment: Then you're going to have to use specific rules specifying the request and redirect. You can't use a catchall like (.*). you'd have to do something like `RewriteRule ^signup\.php systemfiles/signup.php [L]` That's not a complete solution but giving you an example.

Comment: i have like hundreds of files under that folder haha

Comment: Yeah, the way you created the structure is going to force you to have a subfolder of some sort. Why can't just the system files have a subfolder in the URl? `http://example.com/s/singup.php` Then it can still be hidden. `RewriteRule ^s/(.*)$ systemfiles/$1 [L]`

Comment: i guess that is fine i just do not want the templates folder to show

Comment: what do i do with the template folder ?

Comment: use the same format you were using. `http://example.com/somefile.php` goes to templates/somefile.php

Comment: Still not to sure what to do